# Old UK wiring - installing an LED dimmer switch

Tags: wiring, led, uk

[image]I am trying to install this LED dimmer switch - https://www.simplyled.co.uk/phoebe-led-intelligent-smart-touch-sensitive-220w-dimmer-switch-wifi/

please note I am not intending to use the 'smart' function, just liked the design.

To old UK wiring, separate black earth grounded to box. X 2 red cables originally in the L1 of the old switch and another red cable in the Neutral location in the old switch.

Any guidance on how to wire up the new dimmer much appreciated.

Wiring diagram from [manufacturer's instructions](https://www.cromptonlamps.com/files//ffc379bb-ad13-48f9-9a21-ada300f8c1cd/14671-Instructions-2021-web.pdf) -

[image]

Comment: Just because _you_ aren't planning on using the smart switch features doesn't mean that someone in the future (including, possibly, future you) won't. Leaving a partially functional switch isn't a particularly nice thing to do...

Answer (score 1):

Old UK light switches are not compatible with smart switches at all.

You need to drop the unswitched live & neutral from the ceiling to power the smart switch, then use the existing switched loop back to the lamp.

I'm dubious about your description of the existing setup - there is no 'neutral' in a light switch, no matter what the colours are. There is 'com' which is the incoming live & L1/L2 which are the switched lives back to the lamp. Can you add a photo?

Comment: I have added a photo

Comment: The top is com, which is [in theory] your incoming live. The 2 in L1 are the switched live returns to presumably two different lamps - though that's really odd way of doing it. The bits of marker pen probably meant something to whoever installed it - you might find matching markings at the other ends. If you look at the installation diagram in the question, what you currently have is the blue & black going back to the lamp itself [but you can't just use these as-is, you will need to re-wire the rose], you don't have the incoming red & blue.

Comment: New builds have the mains coming up into the wall, old houses have the mains all in the ceiling, with only a switch loop to the switch.

Comment: Just finished insulating and plastering the room so no chance to re-wire now. The room has X2 LED spot lights installed. So this dimmer is no use, time to send back? Are you able to recommend an LED compatible dimmer switch that would work with the existing wiring?

Comment: @Chloe, if those wires are in conduit (basically, a plastic or metal pipe), then you can re-wire  that switch location without damaging the finish of the room. You can pull out the existing wires and pull in new ones without tearing up the walls/ceiling.

Comment: Chloe - we're not supposed to do product recommendations on here - but… if you get an MK [same make as your old switch] it will last a lifetime. Just make sure it says it's for LEDs. I have one that works for both LED & tungsten & has a lovely soft-start so it doesn't go from off to blinding in 1/100th of a second - yes, it's an MK, I wouldn't buy anything else. Cost about 35 quid, though, even with no 'smart' - you get what you pay for;) It could be directly swapped for your existing switch, wired the same. Make sure your LEDs are dimmable on 240v, though. Most aren't.

Comment: This is the kind of product you could just wander into B&Q and ask the staff about - they'll be able to match bulbs to dimmer, no probs.